# How to get value of attribute in array

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_quote_item [_eventObject:protected] => item [_quote:protected] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_quote [_eventObject:protected] => quote [_cacheTag:protected] => quote [_customer:protected] => Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => customer [_eventObject:protected] => customer [_errors:protected] => Array ( ) [_attributes:protected] => [_addresses:protected] => [_addressesCollection:protected] => [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1 [_isReadonly:protected] => [_cacheTag:protected] => customer [_resourceName:protected] => customer/customer [_resource:protected] => [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => customer/customer_collection [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 [_isObjectNew:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [website_id] => 1 [entity_id] => 2 [entity_type_id] => 1 [attribute_set_id] => 0 [email] => vaibhav.ahalpara@brainvire.com [group_id] => 1 [increment_id] => [store_id] => 1 [created_at] => 2014-12-31T22:04:47-08:00 [updated_at] => 2015-01-01 06:24:25 [is_active] => 1 [disable_auto_group_change] => 0 [firstname] => Vaibhav [lastname] => Ahalpara [password_hash] => 7104e363950a3001347bfb592061ba9a:IbYSYS9uHK34kq6hZQJN3SxcGnv8MyZk [created_in] => English [default_billing] => 1 [default_shipping] => 1 [tax_class_id] => 3 ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1 [_origData:protected] => Array ( [website_id] => 1 [entity_id] => 2 [entity_type_id] => 1 [attribute_set_id] => 0 [email] => vaibhav.ahalpara@brainvire.com [group_id] => 1 [increment_id] => [store_id] => 1 [created_at] => 2014-12-31T22:04:47-08:00 [updated_at] => 2015-01-01 06:24:25 [is_active] => 1 [disable_auto_group_change] => 0 [firstname] => Vaibhav [lastname] => Ahalpara [password_hash] => 7104e363950a3001347bfb592061ba9a:IbYSYS9uHK34kq6hZQJN3SxcGnv8MyZk [created_in] =>
```

how can i get value of attribute like

[lastname] => Ahalpara

how can i echo value of [lastname]

Comment: Have you tried `getLastname()`?

Comment: now working ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  get customer first name and last name only w`hen your quote  have Mage_Sales_Quote_Address`.If `Mage_Sales_Quote_Address` Object have Customer first name last name then you can get customer details,other wise you can `not get customer first name  last name.`.

in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` class object is `not give` any Quote address object thus you can not ant direct function which is give proper customer details object

See at class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
  **

```
public function getQuote()
    {
        ....
    }
```

**

```
So ,you can get Quote object by 




$QuoteObject= $itemObject->getQuote();
```

After that you can get customer first ans last name.
   $QuoteObject->getCustomer()->getLastname();

Also you **can get from  Quote Billing object**

```
$QuoteObject->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
```

But `all depends on if you will goes to check step` and **fill customer data**

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you mean by only `getLastname()` but please try with `$item->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getLastname()` or directly `$item->getQuote()->getCustomerLastname()`.

Comment: not Working.....

Comment: Would you please paste the whole code, not the var_dump.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
 {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $product_id=$quote_item->getProduct_id();
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $newprice=$_product->getPrice();
    $newprice=$newprice*10;
    $new_price =$newprice;
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
  }
```